# Using a file page with html and php

Tags: php, html, file

I am trying to get my website to allow people to upload files. I have no idea what I am doing and have tried googling everything I could think of.  I want to limit what they can put in as a file as well as the max file size.  I am also using my PHP code outside of my HTML code.  So any advice I could get would be amazing.  I also tried to follow a tutorial on how to make a file page and it wanted me to use mamp (which I have never used before).  Can someone please help me out?

Here is my PHP code:

```
<?php

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    if (isset($_FILES['files'])) {
        $errors = [];
        $path = 'C:/Users/keena/Desktop/Website/uploads/';
        $extensions = ['pdf', 'txt', 'doc', 'docx'];
    $all_files = count($_FILES['files']['tmp_name']);

    for ($i = 0; $i < $all_files; $i++) {
        $file_name = $_FILES['files']['name'][$i];
        $file_tmp = $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$i];
        $file_type = $_FILES['files']['type'][$i];
        $file_size = $_FILES['files']['size'][$i];
        $file_ext = strtolower(end(explode('.', $_FILES['files']['name'][$i])));

        $file = $path . $file_name;

        if (!in_array($file_ext, $extensions)) {
            $errors[] = 'Extension not allowed: ' . $file_name . ' ' . $file_type;
        }

        if ($file_size > 2097152) {
            $errors[] = 'File size exceeds limit: ' . $file_name . ' ' . $file_type;
        }

        if (empty($errors)) {
            move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, $file);
        }
    }

    if ($errors) print_r($errors);
}
}
```

Here is my HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
<head>

    <php include "process.php"; ?>
    <script src="script/file.js" defer></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/efm.css">
    <title>Education For Ministry</title>
    <meta name="author" content="Keenan J. Norris">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

</head>

<body>

    <a href="index.html">
    <img src="pics/efm-logo.jpg" alt="Education for ministries logo" width="device-width, initial-scale=1.0" height="device-height, initial-scale=1.0"></a>

    <div class="dropdown">
        <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">Menu</button>
        <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="index.html">Home</a>
        <a href="event.html">Events</a>
        <a href="about.html">About</a>
        <a href="login.html">Login</a>
        <a href="enrol.html">Enrollment & Fees</a>
        <a href="resource.html">Resources for Participants</a>
        <a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a>
        <a href="file.html">Files</a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <p>This is for members only.  Please upload pdf, txt, doc, or a docx files.  Files should be no bigger than 2mb.</p>

    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple />
        <input type="submit" value="uploads" name="submit" />
    </form>
</body>
```

P.S. Again I am completely new and have no idea what I am doing.

Answer (score 1):

You can use https://www.dropzonejs.com/ to achieve your file upload. They have complete documentation on how to use it and it's free.

Comment: I would use this but is for a school project I don't think we can use outside websites.  I have a meeting with my career coach.  I will ask her and see what she says.

Comment: for setting up PHP on a local machine you can just follow the video in following link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TjFRTkw6GDQ

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use PHP code, you must setup a server environment with XAMPP if you use Windows or other alternatives.

Tutorial for XAMPP installation: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-f8N4FEQWyY